# Modal Button Inside Table form working as a insert button

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I've created a button to show a modal but the thing is the button is working as an insert into DB as I don't know what's the problem in my code.

I need the modal to show a table of products fetched form the DB and showed as a table form later on in a report.

here's the modal code inside the form..

```
 <div class="container">
    <!-- ======================= Froms ======================= -->
    <form  action="input.php" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Attention:</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <select class="form-control" placeholder="Choose" name="Attention" required="true">
                        <option>Asset</option>
                        <option>Consumable</option>
                        <option>Tool</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">PR No.:</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="PRno">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of 1st Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Project Name:</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <select class="form-control" placeholder="Choose" name="ProjectName">
                        <option>Stock</option>
                        <option>In Use</option>
                        <option>Scrap</option>
                        <option>Lost</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of 2nd Row -->
        <!-- ============== Items Table ============= -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="tab_logic">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Item Description</th>
                            <th>Part Number</th>
                            <th>Unit</th>
                            <th>QTY</th>
                            <th>Unit Price (SR)</th>
                            <th>Total Price (SR)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-4">
                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal">Select ID</button>
                                    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <!-- HEADER | MODAL -->
                                                    <h3 class="modal-title">Title Here</h3>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- BODY | MODAL -->
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    Text Content
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- FOOTER | MODAL -->
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Save changes</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-1">
                                <div>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="PRno">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-2">
                                <div>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="price" step="0.01" min="0.01" max="1000000">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-1" id="deleteBtn">
                                <a class="btn btn-default deleteBtn">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of 3rd Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Add</a>
        </div>
        <!-- End of 4th Row -->
        <!-- ============== Items Table ============= -->
        <div class="input-tigger">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" name="btninsert" value="Insert"  action="input.php" method="post">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and as shown I added the inset button to insert all the form into the DB.

How could the modal work as a insert button instead of the actual button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript/Jquery to prevent the default action of the button and write methods instance of that. I think this will be helpful to you.

```
$(function() // execute once the DOM has loaded
{
  // wire up Add Item button click event
  $("#myButton").click(function(event) //give an ID to modal button
  {
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); //give an ID to modal
    //... rest of add logic
  });
});
```